# How to match sth. "preceeded / followed by" something with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets

I am working with a Google Sheets document in which I need to manipulate strings and extract certain parts of them. These strings have exactly the following form, to the character:

***Ad name: FOO_FOOBAR_DE_CH_Zagreb+N1_970x250.zip; 970x250***

I need to extract two "fields":

- Zagreb
- 970x250

Obviously, the first one is always surrounded by `"\_"` and `"+"` which makes things a bit easier and the other one is either surrounded by `"_"` and `"."` OR preceded by `"; "` if I were to capture it from the end of the string.

I am trying to use Google Sheets proprietary `REGEXMATCH` formula ([read more about it here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en)) but I must be doing something wrong. If it matters, Google products use **RE2** RegEx "flavor".

Here is what I have so far:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(text, "(?:_)[A-Za-z]+(?:\+).*")
```

This one returns:

> _Zagreb+

so I need to lose the "_" and "+". I understand that for this type of operation (extracting text between certain characters) look-arounds should be used but I am still quite unfamiliar with these. Also, I understand that some of them (negative look-behind most notably) do not work with JavaScript.

This is attempt 2:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(text, ".*[A-Za-z]+(?=\+.*)")
```

This one just throws a `#REF` error. I find these two resources invaluable for learning RegEx:

- [Rexegg](http://rexegg.com)
- [Regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info)

but since I am short of time, I can't afford to study this in detail right now.

Comment: FYI: I think you need to use `REGEXEXTRACT` to actually return *texts*, not just TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled it in my Q, i AM using REGEXEXTRACT. Thanks :)

Comment: So, you need to `REGEXEXTRACT`s, right? For Zagreb - `=REGEXEXTRACT(F15,"_([a-zA-Z]+)\+")` and for the resolution, try `=REGEXEXTRACT(F15,";\s*([0-9x]+)$")`

Comment: Bingo! That is it. So I don't actually need to use LOOKAROUNDs? Can it be as simple as this, I simply put what I want to capture in a ( ) and what needs to precede or follow in front or after the capturing group?

Comment: Yes, it is basically it. For such basic extractions, one can leverage the capturing functionality. Lookaheads are only necessary when you have to restrict a more generic pattern, or in case overlapping matches are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Speadsheets, you may use a *capturing group* around the piece of text you need to extract from a specific context. Thus, just place `(` and `)` around those pattern parts.

To get `Zagreb`, use `=REGEXEXTRACT(F15,"_([a-zA-Z]+)\+")` and to get the resolution, use `=REGEXEXTRACT(F15,";\s*([0-9x]+)$")`.

*Pattern 1*:

- `_` - an underscore that is just matched
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - Capture group 1 matching one or more ASCII letters
- `\+` - a literal `+`.

*Pattern 2*

- `;\s*` - a `;` and 0+ whitespaces
- `([0-9x]+)` - Capture group 1 matching one or more digits or `x`
- `$` - at the end of the cell contents.

In both cases, you only get the substrings captured into Group 1.

[image]

More information about [capturing groups can be found here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).